# current property value in get accessor

Tags: c#, properties

How can I get current property value in while get accessor block is running?
I tried to deal with some like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? birthDate
{
    get
    {
        return CommonClass.GetDT(birthDate);
    }
    set
    {
        birthDate = CommonClass.GetDT(value);
    }
}

public class CommonClass
{    
    public static DateTime? GetDT(DateTime v)
    {
        if (v == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
    public static DateTime? GetDT(DateTime? v)
    {
        if (!v.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

But this code is crushed out. But if you look into Microsoft's tutorials you can see some samples that allows to use self property value:

```
public string Name 
{
   get 
   {
      return name != null ? name : "NA";
   }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable and method names are case sensitive which means that "name" and "Name" are different.

```
private string name;   // the name field
public string Name   // the Name property
{
   get 
   {
      return name; 
   }
}
```

So change yours to

```
private DateTime? birthDate
public DateTime? BirthDate
{
    get
    {
        return CommonClass.GetDT(birthDate);
    }
    set
    {
        birthDate = CommonClass.GetDT(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! So easy and elegant solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The get and set accessors of a property are just methods. They are the equivalent of:-

```
public string get_Name()
{
    ...
}

public void set_Name(string value)
{
    ...
}
```

Once you think of them like that, you can see that there is nothing special about them. There is no special 'self' or 'current value'.

In your second code example, there must be a field named 'name' which is used to store the value of the property. This, and nothing else, is the 'current value' of the property.

Comment: Yeah, Adam, I see. But then I try to use my first code sample, it seems like it falls into infinite loop trying getting birthdate's value again and again (I mean this line `return CommonClass.GetDT(birthDate);`). And as a result it getting stack overflow exception error. Thanks!